# What's the proper way to connect a gas line in a cabinet to a stove?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, gas, natural-gas

I recently had a contractor move my stove's gas shutoff valve into a cabinet. He used a [gas range connector](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-4-ft-Gas-Range-Connector-Kit-98255/307638963) to connect the new shutoff valve to my stove. The connector is routed down through the crawl space and back up before coming out the wall behind my stove.

[image]

The more I think about it the more I feel that this is wrong. There is only about 2 feet of pipe left and with cabinets on both sides of my stove, it makes it very difficult to connect/disconnect the stove. My contractor had to crawl over the stove after connecting it.

The warning label on the connector also says it can't be reused. If I ever change my stove or disconnect it, I'll need to replace the connector which will seem like a huge hassle if I have to go into my crawl space and route the connector through the wall.

I'm also reading online that it's unsafe for the gas range connector to be routed through a wall or crawl space. (Not sure if this is true)

First off, is this really an issue or am I overreacting?
If it is an issue, what's the right fix?

Comment: That warning label is not there for fun. Call the gas company and get it looked at. Give them your contractor's info too. You **DO NOT** want to mess with gas. It'll blow up your house and probably kill everyone in it.

Comment: @Nelson LOL, the gas company isn't going to fix it for you. They'll come out, shut off your gas, and put a lock on it until the issue has been addressed. "Hey, thanks for pointing out your hazard. We're just going to shut off your supply until you're up to code. Call us back whenever, thanks!"

Answer (score 1):

> I recently had a contractor move my stove's gas shutoff valve into a cabinet.

Why? Did you request this? Did they do this without permission?

I don't know if they're breaking any rules code-wise but that's up to your local inspector's discretion.

Someday when the flex line needs to be replaced then it can be disconnected inside the cabinet, routed through your crawl space, and pushed back into your kitchen so that you can move the stove away from the wall.

Is this more of a hassle? Yes. Is it against code? I don't know, the shutoff is accessible so it might be fine albeit in general you should always take precaution to install flex lines away from potential damage. The inside of a cabinet with large pots seems like a bad idea in that regard.

Comment: *The inside of a cabinet with large pots seems like a bad idea in that regard.* I don't see that as a problem. The issue of "away from potential damage" is where you can't see the flex (the part *under* the cabinets).

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Why not? It's a location of high traffic potential. It would be trivial to get careless and shove a pot too far in or have a playful baby doing hide-n-seek. As for not being able to see the flex hose beneath the cabinet; are there different rules for appliance connectors versus CSST?

Comment: Well, I disagree - once you get used to layout of a particular cabinet, easy enough to know where to put stuff to avoid problems. Plus flex is *flexible* so it can take some movement/bumps. Baby hide/seek? I definitely would not want that in a cabinet with gas pipe - flex as you mentioned but I'd also worry about bumping the hard valves & pipe, etc. As far as flex hose under cabinet - don't know if that's a code issue. My *general* understanding is that it should be used only within one cabinet - i.e., literally just the last segment of the connection.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Someday I too shall be perfect but until then I'll be fixing the drain under my sink a few more times because I keep bumping the trash can into drain line. If you read the directions for appliance connectors they explicitly state to avoid movement except for occasional cleaning. I cannot find an Everbilt manual per OP's post but see https://www.brasscraft.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/BrassCraft-CFS-Kit-Installation-Instructions.pdf and read warnings 6 and 7 on page 1.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact A new homeowner or babysitter might not be afforded the chance to "learn the layout of a cabinet" before something goes ka-boom so it's better to err on the side of caution.

Comment: In all seriousness, what is the alternative? Waste a big under-cooktop cabinet? Those are actually ideal for pots & pans.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact The alternative is for OP to tell us **why** the shutoff valve was moved into a problematic position in the first place. What was the perceived benefit and why was an alternative not chosen. A hard pipe should have come up through the floor behind the stove like any other sane install I've seen.

Comment: Actually, I agree that this particular setup was not done right (i.e., not best practices, whether or not it satisfies code). I am just saying that *in general* flex in a cabinet (one cabinet, not looping to a second cabinet) is perfectly fine, even with pots & pans and kids etc.

Comment: We bought a slide-in stove that did not slide in all the way because the existing gas pipe was in the way. Our contractor was the one who recommended to move the shutoff valve into the cabinet because he said that was safer and to current code. Justification from him was that in the event of an emergency, we would have an easier time to shut off the gas.

Comment: I looked it up and there are different rules for CSST vs a gas connector. CSST is a pipe equivalent so it can be routed through walls.

Comment: @user786362 Good thought, bad execution. The back of a range should have an indent for this exact reason. Watch https://youtu.be/Ewsxmtn3dwk and share it with your contractor. He has created a hazard, plain and simple.

Comment: @user786362 I'm sorry but the contractor has created the following issues: cannot pull the stove out for easy cleaning, lost cabinet space, potential for gas line damage via pots and appliances, gas appliance connectors should not go through floors and walls for risk of abrasion and damage especially if a less informed person tries really hard to move the stove in the future. Yes, future people will absolutely pull the stove too hard before they ever attempt to realize "Hey, something is stuck, maybe I shouldn't continue pulling."

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Watch https://youtu.be/Ewsxmtn3dwk for how this should have been properly done.

Comment: Thanks for the YouTube link. I’ll show it to the contractor.

Comment: Excellent video.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Once you see something done right you no longer appreciate cavalier ingenuity =)